# how can i loop inside my views with query in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}    

    products_page_all = ProductsPageAll.objects.all()
    context_dict['products_page_all'] = products_page_all

    for x in products_page_all:    
        pages = ProductsPageViews.objects.filter(product=x)
        context_dict['pages'] = pages


    home_page = HomePage.objects.all()[:1].get()
    context_dict['home_page'] = home_page

    extras_page_blog = ExtrasPageBlog.objects.all().latest('blog_date')
    context_dict['extras_page_blog'] = extras_page_blog

    extras_page_news_events = ExtrasPageNewsEvents.objects.all().latest('news_or_events_date')
    context_dict['extras_page_news_events'] = extras_page_news_events

    aboutus_team = AboutUsPageTeam.objects.all()
    context_dict['aboutus_team'] = aboutus_team
    # Return a rendered response to send to the client.
    # We make use of the shortcut function to make our lives easier.
    # Note that the first parameter is the template we wish to use.
    return render(request, 'pec/index.html', context_dict)
```

In the above code i get all objects  in products_page_all.

I then want to iterate through this objects and store the filter content for each object. I only get the last object in filter in my page key of dictionary.
Here is my model:

```
class ProductsPageAll(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True) 
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/products')
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_name
        return self.product_description

class ProductsPageViews(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductsPageAll)
    product_view_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/products/views')
    product_view_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_view_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product_view_content
        return self.product_view_description
```

and my html below

```
{% for page in pages %}
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="{{page.product_view_image.url}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <h4 class="service-heading">{{page.product_view_content}}</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{page.product_view_description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you are trying to do, and what happens that you want to change?

Comment: i want to iterate through all the objects of products_page_all and then using that object i want to filter my ProductsPageViews model and get all the objects of that model in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is here:

```
for x in products_page_all:    
    pages = ProductsPageViews.objects.filter(product=x)
    context_dict['pages'] = pages
```

You are overriding the key 'pages' each iteration, so the value at key pages will be the last iteration. One way to loop all your pages belonging to to a ProductsPageAll would just be loop over the reverse relationship:

```
for productpage in products_page_all:
    for page in productpage.productspageviews_set.all:
        #do something with the page object
```

Comment: how can i create a dynamic dictionary(to create dynamic key) to store pages.